# Apache POI jar taking long time to generate excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, logging, jar, apache-poi

```
public class WriteToExcel {
 / Initialize logger object 
 Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WriteToExcel.class.getName());

 public void write(Map> preparedData, String fileName) {

    // Define a workbook and a sheet for the report`enter code here`
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("REPORT");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        Set keySet = preparedData.keySet();
        List list = new ArrayList(keySet);

        // Read config.properties 
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("./config.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);

        System.out.println("inside excel Collections in" );
        // Sort the list so that heading row will come as first row
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("inside excel Collections out" );

        int rowNum = 0; 
      int count1 =0, count2 =0;
        // Add data to the workbook
        for (String key : list) {
            System.out.println("inside excel string key"+ ++count1 );
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            List objectArray = preparedData.get(key);
            int cellNum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objectArray) {
                System.out.println("inside excel object for loop "+ ++count2 );
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);

                if (obj instanceof Date)
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);


            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOutputSTream;
        Calendar todaysDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        String todaysFormattedDate = Util.formatDateUnderscore(todaysDate);

        try {

            String filePath = properties.getProperty("filePath");

            String completeFilename = filePath + fileName + "_"
                    + todaysFormattedDate + ".xls";
            fileOutputSTream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    completeFilename));
            workbook.write(fileOutputSTream);
            fileOutputSTream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            log.error("FileNotFoundException : ", e);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception : ", e);
    }

 }
}
```

Seeking assistance in determining what is wrong with the code loop; why is it taking so long/creating this issue?

Comment: 500 records it is taking 25min to write in excel , can you any tell me what was wrong ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear at all. I personally cannot understand what the code is supposed to be doing. Can you provide a brief summary of what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: markdown, clarification, grammar, tag

Comment: Add information to the logs to see where it is taking so long. Something simple like `System.out.println(new Date + " inside excel Collections out" );` . The excel part seems normal and should not take that long.

Comment: Did you try [following the Apache POI FAQ entry on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165)?